# Critical points of $f(z)=z^2$ when extended to riemann sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Writing $z=x+iy$, and with the standard charts $(U_0,\varphi_0)$ and $(U_1,\varphi_1)$, we can identify the plane with $U_0$ and we get a unique smooth extension to the riemann sphere, which corresponds to $\overline{f}([z:w])=z^2$. Computing the jacobian of $\varphi_0\circ \overline{f}\circ\varphi_0^{-1}$ we get

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} 2x& -2y\\ 2y&2x \end{array}\right]$$

And so the points $z$ with $x=y$ should correspond to critical points of $\overline{f}$. However, we have that $\varphi_1\circ\overline{f}\circ\varphi_1$ is constant, and thus every point in $U_1\cap U_0=U_0/\lbrace 0\rbrace$ should be a critical point. Clearly these things can't both be true. What am I doing incorrectly/missing here?

Comment: $\det \nabla f = 4x^2+4y^2= 4\Re(z)^2+4\Im(z)^2$ which has only one root $z=0$. Since $f$ is holomoprhic you could see it directly from $f'(z) = 0 \implies z=0$. In the other chart you'll have the point at $\infty$ as another branch point.